# Kotlin - very frequent data removal and addition to a list causes npe

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin

I've a `buffer` that is actually `ArrayList<Object>`.

**Happens async:**
This `buffer` list changes very frequently - I mean **15-50 times in single second** and the idea is that whenever there's an update, I remove first element by position `buffer.removeAt(0)` and add new value in the end by `buffer.add(new)`.

At some point I call a function that goes and do calculation with `buffer` list. What I do is I go through the list - element by element. At some point I run into NPE as the the element has been removed async.

How to solve this NPE? I was thinking of making `deep copy`, but making deep copy would mean to go through the `buffer` list and do some data allocation, which basically means that while I do deep copy I can still run into NPE.

How problems like these are solved?

1. How to solve NPE?
2. What would be more optimized way as this is gonna consume a lot of memory?

Code:

```
private fun observeFrequentData() {
    frequentData.observe(owner, Observer { data ->
        if (accelerationData == null) return@Observer

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val a = data[0].toDouble()
            val b = data[1].toDouble()

            val c = a + b
            val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val customObj = CustomObj(c, timestamp)

            if (buffer.size >= 5000) {
                buffer.removeAt(0)
            }

            buffer.add(acceleration)
        }
    })
}


fun getBuffer() {
     val mappedData = buffer.map { it.smth } // NPE, it == null
}
```

Comment: You have to syncronize your calls or use copy-on-read where you copy the list before you calculate the values.

Comment: Just use a proper concurrent queue: `ArrayBlockingQueue`. No manual synchronization needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing lots of removing from 0, and insert at the end. Then ArrayList is probably not the container to use.

you can consider using a  [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) .

```
buffer.removeFirst();
```

and

```
buffer.add(acceleration);
```

also note the following comments regarding synchronization.

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A
>   structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more elements; merely setting the value of an element is not a
>   structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by
>   synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If
>   no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the
>   Collections.synchronizedList method. This is best done at creation
>   time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:

```
   List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList(...));
```

Comment: And the `Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList(...))` should happen in getBuffer() [in my case] at the very beginning, right?

Comment: @PeteWonder. yes, in the very beginning. although you can also do what patrick recommends. i.e. add a synchronize around the parts where buffer is being ammended.

Comment: As I understand the "synchronized" works as a lock. If that's true, shouldn't I set this lock when getBuffer() is called, meaning, that it happens very rare, but when it happens, I want it to have first priority touching the buffer.

Comment: you want to keep the locked period as small as possible. hence only at places in your codes where the data is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

Using the synchronized keyword on your piece of code as @patrickf suggested.

To take care of performance, instead of making the method call itself synchronized, you can just write the 3 "buffer" related lines of code (size, removeAt and add) in a synchronized block.

Something like;

```
.
.
.
   synchronized {
          if (buffer.size >= 5000) {
                buffer.removeAt(0)
            }

            buffer.add(acceleration)
   }
}
})
```

Hope this helps!